# Error when flashing recovery to Moto G4 Plus Xt1640 - Image not signed or corrupt

Tags: rooting, adb, rom-flashing, fastboot, motorola-moto-g

I recently bought a new android phone (Moto g4 plus). Coming from the iPhone, I was eager to root it and take advantage of all the features.

The problem is that whenever I try to flash a recovery image, I get this error:

```
C:\Users\myuser\adb>fastboot flash recovery recovery.img
target reported max download size of 536870912 bytes
sending 'recovery' (12496 KB)...
OKAY [  0.400s]
writing 'recovery'...
(bootloader) Image not signed or corrupt

OKAY [  0.197s]
finished. total time: 0.601s
```

Keep in mind that the bootloader IS unlocked, I even get the warning when restarting the phone. Also this does not happen with just one image file. Every single image file gets this error. I have tried many different versions of TWRP, CLW, etc and all of them get this same error. Does anyone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yeah, I had the same error. The US XT1644 variant can't use the boot.img for the XT1643 and below. I was able to root by installing SuperSU. Run this command:

fastboot boot twrp-3.0.2-0-athene.img

Make sure you copy the SuperSU zip file in the /sdcard/TWRP folder on your device. Then when twrp loads, you can just pick the zip file and install.