# Cannot flash twrp-3.2.3-0-cedric.img (Motorola Moto G5) ("Image not signed or corrupt")

Tags: twrp, fastboot, linux, lineageos, motorola-moto-g5

I have followed all the steps of [this guy](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kclxUJRQJZw) but flashing `twrp-3.2.3-0-cedric.img` failed.

When I open my Ubuntu console and type `fastboot flash recovery /home/username/folder/twrp-3.2.3-0-cedric.img`, it says:

```
(bootloader) slot-count: not found
(bootloader) slot-suffixes: not found
(bootloader) slot-suffixes: not found
(bootloader) has-slot:recovery: not found
target reported max download size of 536870912 bytes
sending 'recovery' (14572 KB)...
OKAY [  0.463s]
writing 'recovery'...
(bootloader) Image not signed or corrupt
OKAY [  0.502s]
finished. total time: 0.965s
```

What did I do wrong? Did I use the wrong version? Looking at [this similar problem](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/150358/271628) did not help me. `sudo fastboot flash recovery /home/username/folder/twrp-3.2.3-0-cedric.img` does not help either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The locked bootloader doesn’t let unsigned images to be flashed. So, the `Image not signed...` error indicates that there is a possibility of the bootloader not being unlocked.

- Make sure the bootloader is unlocked.
- Make sure you are using right version of TWRP for your device.
- Try `fastboot boot /path/to/twrp.img` instead of flashing. If it boots, flash the recovery image from within the recovery. Afterwards, any `zip` should be successfully flashed (custom ROM, GApps, mods etc.).

Comment: `fastboot boot  /path/to/twrp.img`    boot and path shoud have space in between